# Filter out href in a list instead of soup.find_all

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Hi I filter out some of the announcement on a website with the following script

```
 gdata_even=soup.find_all("li", {"class":"list2Col even "})
 gdata_odd=soup.find_all("li", {"class":"list2Col odd "})
```

Finally I only take some of the announcements in gdata depending on whether the item has a certain word:

```
for l in range(len_data):
            if _checkDate(gdata_even[l].text):
                if _checkwordsV2(gdata_even[l].text):
                    pass
                else:
                    initial_list.append(gdata_even[l].text.encode("utf-8"))

            if _checkDate(gdata_odd[l].text):
                if _checkwordsV2(gdata_odd[l].text):
                    pass
                else:
                    initial_list.append(gdata_odd[l].text.encode("utf-8"))
```

The problem I am facing now is that gdata_even[l] and gdata_odd[l] has the following output:

```
<li class="list2Col even "><div class="indexCol"><span class="date">25 Aug 2015 12:00:06 AM CEST</span></div><div class="contentCol"><div class="categories">Frankfurt</div><h3><a href="/xetra-en/newsroom/xetra-newsboard/FRA-Deletion-of-Instruments-from-XETRA---25.08.2015-001/1913134">FRA:Deletion of Instruments from XETRA - 25.08.2015-001</a></h3></div></li>
```

Here I want to get the link of the item which is embedded in the href with the following code but it doesn't work:

```
    h3Url = gdata[l].find("a").get("href")
    print h3Url
```

Can someone please assist, thank you.

Comment: What is the error or what are you getting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe there is an error on how you are getting gdata because your code should work.

```
>>> from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
>>> doc='<li class="list2Col even "><div class="indexCol"><span class="date">25 Aug 2015 12:00:06 AM CEST</span></div><div class="contentCol"><div class="categories">Frankfurt</div><h3><a href="/xetra-en/newsroom/xetra-newsboard/FRA-Deletion-of-Instruments-from-XETRA---25.08.2015-001/1913134">FRA:Deletion of Instruments from XETRA - 25.08.2015-001</a></h3></div></li>'
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(doc)
>>> h3Url = soup.find('a').get('href')
>>> print h3Url

/xetra-en/newsroom/xetra-newsboard/FRA-Deletion-of-Instruments-from-XETRA---25.08.2015-001/1913134
```